# Mocking a public method that has a private method call inside using Mockito (not Powermockito)

Tags: mockito, junit5

I am testing for methodA() in the class :

```
class Test{
 public String methodA(String str){
  ...
  methodB("s1","s2");
  ...
 }
 private String methodB(String s1, String s2){
   ...
 }
}
```

What I have tried in my test class:

```
Method methodBReflect = Test.class.getDeclaredMethod("methodB", Test.class,String.class, String.class);
methodBReflect.setAccessible(true);
Test testForSpy=new Test();
Test spyTest=spy(testForSpy);
doReturn("return string").when(spyTest..)... // <-- What should be done here?
//methodBReflect.invoke(spyTest, "args1","args2");
```

P.S: I don't need a solution using powermock as I have some organizational constraints using it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be testing that method A calls method B.  You should test that method A does what method A is supposed to do - that is, it gives the correct output for whatever input you give it.  Your test shouldn't care whether method A works by calling method B, or by doing all its processing inline.

Therefore, there's no need to mock or stub anything.  Your tests will consist of a bunch of calls to method A, along with verification that the output is what you expect.

You only need to use Mockito (or some other mocking framework) when you're testing a class that interacts with another class entirely; not when the class under test interacts with itself.

Comment: That made sense (and solved my problem as well). Upvoting it. I am new to the Mockito framework and I was just wondering one thing, why is there an option to achieve the same in PowerMock? I do get it's not a good testing practice/logically we shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: As a general principle, Mockito was originally designed in a way that would help guide people towards good testing practices.  Things that the designers of Mockito (principally Szczepan Faber) deemed to be poor practice, such as mocking private methods, were made impossible.  PowerMock came along to allow people to do all the things that Mockito wouldn't let them do.  In general, if you think you need to use PowerMock for something, there's a good chance it's because you're doing something you shouldn't.